# randomly select a word between commas in php string

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this

```
$genres = "pop,rock,jazz,80s";
```

i was wondering is it possible to then create a string that randomly selects any of those genres above? but removing the comma?

for example it would create

```
$newgenre = "pop";
```

Comment: didn't you already post something similar ealier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369338/is-it-possible-to-put-an-array-into-a-php-string an you were given a few answers. What's the status of that one? You didn't post a comment under any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$genreArray = explode(',', $genres);
$genre = $genreArray[mt_rand(0, count($genreArray))];
```

Comment: This is giving me an error : [18-Nov-2017 19:58:51 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ']' in

Comment: `mt_rand()` is better than rand. [**why?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: As of 7.1, `rand()` has become an alias for `mt_rand()`, but I've changed it for backwards compatibility. Thanks, @Martin! -CM

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative Method

Everyone else is using random selection from an array, try this alternative:

```
$genreArray = explode(',', $genres);
shuffle($genreArray);     //mixes up the array using rand or mt_rand 
$genre = $genreArray[0];  // take first element of shuffled array.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$genreArray = explode(',', $genres)` function to put it all into an array.
Then you can generate a random index for the array, using

```
$randomKey = rand(0, count($genreArray))
```

And then, all you have to do is take the random genre from the array.

```
$randomGenre = $genreArray[$randomKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explode

and get a random value from the array

```
$genresArray = explode(',',$genres);

$your_values = array_rand ($genresArray,1);

echo $your_values[0];
```